# How to find directories within the directory the index.html file is stored within using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, search

I'm using an input box, when the search button is pressed I want to see if the searched term is an existing directory within the directory that the `index.html` file is stored within. Here's the code so far:

```js
function searchWebs () {
    var searchedTermRaw = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;
    var searchedTerm    = searchedTermRaw.toUpperCase();
    if (searchedTerm == "") {
        return;
    } else {
        if (searchedTerm == "NUMI" || searchedTerm == "ELMDON PM") {
            document.getElementById('searchFor').innerHTML        = "Search results for '" + searchedTermRaw + "'.";
            document.getElementById('searchForDetails').innerHTML = "";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('searchFor').innerHTML        = "No search results were found for '" + searchedTermRaw + "'.";
            document.getElementById('searchForDetails').innerHTML = "Please use the ID provided within the email Netwal sent you, if you have not been sent an email with the ID, your website isn't ready for viewing/testing yet.";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="searchBox" placeholder="Website ID">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br>
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-lg-12" onclick="searchWebs();">Search</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 id="searchFor"></h1>
                <p id="searchForDetails"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to replace the if statement for checking if the search term is NUMI or ELMDON PM with checking if the directory exists.

Comment: There must be a way through AJAX to get an HTTP response about wheter the directory url is valid or doesn't exist. Someone more savvy than me could probably tell you more about that. An easy way would be to process the request server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method `isAvailable(url)` and pass the path or `searchedTerm`

Make sure to maintain the cross-origin policy.

I have added baseUrl as `https://stacksnippets.net/` for that issue.

```
var baseUrl = "https://stacksnippets.net/";

function isAvailable(url) {
  url = baseUrl + url;
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('HEAD', url, false);
  try {
    http.send();
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
  return http.status != 404;
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

I tried term `js` which will produce url https://stacksnippets.net/js

> **I am afraid the example will not work due to cross-origin and mixed-content errors but this approach should work in your case.**

***You can check for your resource in your domain by changing the `baseUrl`***

**SNIPPET**

```js
function searchWebs() {
  var searchedTermRaw = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;
  var searchedTerm = searchedTermRaw.toUpperCase();
  if (searchedTerm == "") {
    return;
  } else {
    if (isAvailable(searchedTerm)) {
      document.getElementById('searchFor').innerHTML = "Search results for '" + searchedTermRaw + "'.";
      document.getElementById('searchForDetails').innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('searchFor').innerHTML = "No search results were found for '" + searchedTermRaw + "'.";
      document.getElementById('searchForDetails').innerHTML = "Please use the ID provided within the email Netwal sent you, if you have not been sent an email with the ID, your website isn't ready for viewing/testing yet.";
    }
  }
}

var baseUrl = "https://stacksnippets.net/";

function isAvailable(url) {
  url = baseUrl + url;
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('HEAD', url, false);
  try {
    http.send();
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
  return http.status != 404;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="searchBox" placeholder="Website ID">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <br>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-lg-12" onclick="searchWebs();">Search</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 id="searchFor"></h1>
        <p id="searchForDetails"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```